# No module named 'telegram' error after installing python-telegram-bot

Tags: visual-studio, python-telegram-bot

I have installed the python-telegram-bot from cmd using this:
`pip install python-telegram-bot` 
and also I tried this `pip install telegram`

but after I run a code using Visual studio I receive this error message:

- Message=No module named 'telegram'
- 

and Visual studio highlight this line of code :
`import telegram.ext`

I have tried installing python-telegram-bot several times
So I entered cmd and I used `pip install python-telegram-bot` and also `pip install python-telegram-bot --upgrade` and also `pip install telegram` but it does not work I think I have to install it for Visual Studio somehow

Comment: I also reinstalled python-telegram-bot

Answer (score 2):

`telegram` and `python-telegram-bot` are not the same packages. In fact, the `telegram` package is just namesquatting and it doesn't contain any functionality - see https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/1252 for details.
So be sure to uninstall `telegram` via `pip uninstall telegram -y` and then install ptb via `pip install python-telegram-bot`.

Now to your actual problem: The editor highlighting `import telegram.ext` is rather surely a false positive. This is due to the pypi project being named `python-telegram-bot` while the library provides a package called `telegram`. Your editor probably just can't make that connection and thinks that the `telegram` package is not available.

If you get actual exceptions at runtime - i.e. `python my_script.py` raises exceptions about the `telegram` package missing - you'll need to double check that you installed PTB to same same python version/environment that you use to run the script.